# no resource identifier found when using AndroidTreeView

Tags: java, android, treeview

I tried using AndroidTreeView

https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView

But after following the directions and importing it, i now receive the following errors in resource layout_selectable_item.xml which i copied into my project from the demo that came with the package.

```
 Error:(37) No resource identifier found for attribute 'iconText' in package 'android'
 Error:(37) No resource identifier found for attribute 'iconColor' in package 'android'
 Error:(37) No resource identifier found for attribute 'iconFont' in package 'android'
 Error:(37) No resource identifier found for attribute 'iconSize' in package 'android'
```

If i comment out the lines with the error from the xml file, the treeView works, but there are no icons in it, and it looks crappy, so I think these lines are needed but of course the errors...

To import it all i did was add this line to the gradle then started using the tree view in my code, and it worked (but looks crappy)..

```
compile 'com.github.bmelnychuk:atv:1.2.+'
```

Here is the xml file, can anybody help????

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="48dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<CheckBox
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/node_selector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/node_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/picture_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top_line"
        android:background="#12558C"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp" />

    <com.github.johnkil.print.PrintView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:iconText="@string/ic_check_circle_blank"
        android:iconColor="#12558C"
        android:iconFont="fonts/material-icon-font.ttf"
        android:iconSize="16dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bot_line"
        android:background="#12558C"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp" />
</LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/picture_wrapper"
    android:id="@+id/node_value"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where are those 4 attributes documented?  I don't see styleables declared under the resources folder.

Comment: Submersed, i dont know where they are declared, or supposed to be declared. I will check for stylables as you mentioned, Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your app level gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

From github page: https://github.com/johnkil/Print

> **Custom views**
>
> Use PrintView as single icon in your layout.
>
> ```
>  <com.github.johnkil.print.PrintView
>          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>          app:print_iconText="@string/ic_android"
>          app:print_iconColor="@color/icon_color"
>          app:print_iconSize="@dimen/icon_size"/>
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that and it didnt work, gave the exact same error

Comment: Then you have not imported all your resources to "res" folder.  Try going 1 by 1, start from iconText, check if String/ic_check_circle_blank, then move down to icon_Size. 
P.S. change icon_Fonts to: @fonts/.....

Comment: Thanks, if you are talking about defining the strings in the string.xml yes i did that

Comment: Error:(38) No resource identifier found for attribute 'print_iconText' in package 'com.example.ns.yogigapp'
Error:(38) No resource identifier found for attribute 'print_iconColor' in package 'com.example.ns.yogigapp'
Error:(38) No resource identifier found for attribute 'print_iconSize' in package 'com.example.ns.yogigapp'

Answer (score 0):

Add implementation 'com.github.johnkil.print:print:1.3.1' into your build.gradle file.
Also don't forget to add material-icon-font.ttf to main/assets/fonts

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
PrintConfig.initDefault(getAssets(), "fonts/material-icon-font.ttf");
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the app namespace, not android:

```
 <com.github.johnkil.print.PrintView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:iconText="@string/ic_check_circle_blank"
        app:iconColor="#12558C"
        app:iconFont="fonts/material-icon-font.ttf"
        app:iconSize="16dp" />
```

Comment: See comment on question please.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, just kept trying different things dont know what combination of things made it work unfortunatly.